# how do I change the user that git is running under?

Tags: git, groups

Maybe my question is not quite correctly formulated, but nevertheless: I have an old server A and a new server B with ispmanager panels - I did not personally configure the software. In the old server, the repository data (PHP program code) that I copied from the git has the owner www-root, in the new one - root. This causes problems with creating directories, files, etc. How do I make git clone copy the program code with the www-root owner?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].